# NSPersistentDocument: browse versions : Attempt to add read-only file

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, versions, nspersistentdocument

Because I am using a custom core data stack, I am overwriting the `init, readFromURL, writeToURL`, and `revertToContentsOfURL` functions.

When I click "Browse all versions", previous versions of my file are openend and init is called. However I get the following error:

> Attempt to add read-only file at path ... Adding it read-only instead.
>      This will be a hard error in the future;
>      you must specify the NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption.

My question is now: how do I know if the file being opened is a regular file or a versioned file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it. In a subclass of NS(Persistent)Document, when determining the options for your NSPersistentStore.

```
if self.inViewingMode {
     [NSSQLitePragmasOption: yourPragmaOptions,
      NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption: "YES"] }
```